# Can't run tomcat7

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using AngularJS. I worked on windows, but I transfered my project to Ubuntu 14.04. There is tomcat7 on ubuntu computer. 
This is error:

```
 /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run   
 Connected to the target VM,  address: '127.0.0.1:33493', transport: 'socket'
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
 WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFO: Initialization processed in 2065 ms
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
 INFO: Starting service Catalina
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 Oct 12, 2015 3:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 179 ms Connected to server
```

Comment: It seems you are facing http://askubuntu.com/questions/487374/how-to-install-tomcat7-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts - you need to repair your Tomcat installation.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek It did not help me

Comment: Why are you running catalina.sh directly as the logged-in user?  That is likely to present permissions issues, particularly if you're root.  Why not use "sudo service tomcat start" instead?

Comment: Then you have to share more details about your environment (i.e. how is the Tomcat installed o Ubuntu, how it was installed on Windows, how did you transfer your project (copied only the webapp directory? deployed WAR file? ...) etc.). The above log excerpt is not enough to say what's happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't necessarily errors. `Server startup in 179 ms Connected to server` means your server did start up. It seems more likely you haven't actually deployed your application to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`. It also needs to be readable by the `tomcat7` user.